# Change folder name using makefile

Tags: makefile

I know how to change the file-extensions:

```
JS_MINIFIED = $(patsubst %.js,%-min.js,$(JS_FILES))
```

or

```
JS_MINIFIED = $(JS_FILES:.js=-min.js)
```

But what if I want to change the actual folder. e.g. dump everything in a "temp" folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite know what you mean.  Do you mean that for every file in JS_FILES, regardless of its path, you want to put it into "temp"?  So "foo/bar/biz.js" goes to "temp/biz.js", and "one/two/three.js" goes to "temp/three.js"?  Then maybe:

```
JS_MINIFIED = $(addprefix temp/,$(notdir $(JS_FILES)))
```

Or do you want to preserve the same structure but prefix it with "temp"?  So "foo/bar/biz.js" goes to "temp/foo/bar/biz.js", and "one/two/three.js" goes to "temp/one/two/three.js"?  Then just:

```
JS_MINIFIED = $(addprefix temp/,$(JS_FILES))
```